# Cookies, document.cookie vs cookies in the inspector dev tool

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies, browser

When I inspect a page via chrome dev tools there is a very large list of cookies, as opposed to when using document.cookie there are only a few.

[image]

Can anyone explain the difference between these cookies and the ones via my console.log, and why I can not access them via javascript?

Is it even possible to get these cookies I see in the dev tool using javascript?
Do I need to set them manually first?

Thanks!

Comment: 3rd party cookies

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,

Are you saying my cookies are 3rd party, or the cookies in the dev tool?
Is it possible to access these cookies I see in the dev tools?

Comment: Well you see them in the dev tools, not sure what you mean by access them. JavaScript can only touch the cookies that are valid for the domain it is in.

Comment: My main goal is to store individual cookies in their own variables. So for example I would want to get the value of "ANON" by its name and store its value for later use. But every time I try, i get a value of "Undefined"

Comment: Are those cookies from your domain or not? Is `http://.....basic.com` the current domain in the address bar?

Comment: Yes, it is the same domain.

Comment: And how are you accessing the cookies?

Comment: Im using https://github.com/florian/cookie.js, cookie.get('key'); and var cookies = cookie.all();